# How to properly use the ngRoute using the #!

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have this in my Login.cshtml

```
<div class="contact-widget" data-loader="button">
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
</div>
```

and to change the view I have this:

```
<ul class="one-page-menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="#!/Login/CreateAccount"><div>Create Account</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/Login"><div>Login</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

in my app.js, I have this:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Login", {
            templateUrl: "/Partials/LoginPartial.html",
            controller: "LogInController"
        })
        .when("/CreateAccount", {
            templateUrl: "/Partials/CreateAccountPartial.html",
            controller: "CreateAccountController"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Login" });
}])
```

this is in my controller to view the login

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I click on the Login link to view the login form I get this in the Url `http://localhost:18223/Login/Login/#!/Login` and when I click the createaccount link I get this `http://localhost:18223/Login/Login/#!/CreateAccount`
but I can see the view change. My problem is; how do I make the Url get to be like this `http://localhost:18223/Login/Login` for both loginview and createaccount view

Comment: Have you enabled `$locationProvider.html5Mode`? Did you use `<base>` tag? Have you modified `.htaccess` file for routing?

Comment: I didn’t use them coz I’m new to angular and I didn’t know that you have to use all of those to get to my goal. Thanks.